# Compare WKInterfaceLabel Text to Another NSString

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

I know there is no getter method for WKInterfaceLabel, but is there another way for me to compare the label text to another string? If this wasn't a watch app and I was using UILabel I could just do this:

```
if ([self.label.text isEqualToString:someString]) {

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no supported way to get the text, just as you said, however you may want to use the accessibility elements as "option".

Here's the idea:

When self.label text is set (either in code or storyboard) also set the corresponding accessibility label/value.  When you need to read/update the label text, just make sure you use the accessibility values instead.

```
self.label.text = @"foo";
self.label.accessibilityValue = @"foo";

if ([self.label.accessibilityValue isEqualToString:someString]) {
   self.label.text = @"bar";
   self.label.accessibilityValue = @"bar";
   ...
}
```

Plus it's how you would use accessibility anyway so it's *legal*.  There may be other ways to accomplish, but this seems to be the quickest and safest way to do what you want.

Comment: I was writing my own answer to suggest using an NSString property to keep a copy of the text stored in WKInterfaceLabel. But I like this answer better.

Comment: This doesn't work in Swift 4 as there is now no accessibilityValue attribute. 
Just like text, there's only setAccessibilityValue, and no getter!