# Get a float value when there is no getter method for WKInterfaceLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to get a float value from a `WKInterfaceLabel`.  As there is no getter method for `WKInterfaceLabel`, using `float x = ([_someText.text floatValue]);` will just give me no getter method error. Any ideas?

I tried here [Compare WKInterfaceLabel Text to Another NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703534/compare-wkinterfacelabel-text-to-another-nsstring) to find a solution, using `self.label.accessibilityValue` simply returns `nil` when acessing the `accessibilityValue`

Comment: Did you first *set* the accessibilityValue ?  To use the solution in that thread you linked to, you must "mirror" the label text with the accessibilityValue-- always set them both to the new value, is the only way it will work.

Comment: Yep, it was `set` in the first instance and read from that.  Always getting nil

Answer (score 0):

A few different solutions / ideas:

I would make your `WKInterfaceLabel` a property and synthesize it, then you are able to retrieve float values from your label just like you would with a regular `UILabel`. I've successfully done this with no issues. I checked out the post that you linked and they said there is currently no way to retrieve the text values... I don't know if something was updated or not because I can retrieve float values, text values etc in WatchKit just fine. For retrieving or settingy code looks exactly like this:

(Declared privately in the .m)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *tempoLabel;
//
    - (void)setTempoFromInteger {
        self.tempoLabel.text = @"";
    if (tempo > 0 && tempo < 999) {
        NSString *tempoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tempo];
        self.tempoLabel.text = tempoString;
    }
 }
```

Now if you're trying to just receive a random float value rather than create, you had to of retrieved or set that float value SOMEWHERE in your code or if retrieved from a server, somewhere in the data. Save that, and use it.

Comment: My `WKInterfaceLabels` are  properties already.  How are you obtaining  a getter? `WKInterfaceLabel` is a read from property only with no getter method? (Xcode V6.3) I cant get anything from WKInterface label at all?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have run into the same brick wall?

Comment: @d.altman  I wish the has site private messaging so that I could message everybody my project showing them how I did it. I will check it out and keep you all updated via this posting